How to Use Tokenization in Language Model?
I've been training this LM, with these hyper parameters:
blocksiz = 128
batchsiz = 32
nemb = 256
nhead = 4
nlayers = 4
evalIters = 100
lr = 3e-4
epochs = 30

my Dataset is 93kb.. ,
I'm using GPT-2 as Tokenizer..
However its take way too long to train, while i'm using With GPT-2 Tokenizer,
but when i train the model as bigram. it didn't take that much.
So Using GPT2 as tokenizer which has 50257 Vocabsiz, will Effect the Model Trainin..?
Is it take Take More GPU resources to Train..?
So for Small dataset. What Should i use as Tokenizer ...?
i Decrease the Hyper parameters, parameters i use above is a result of Decreasing
But the Model is take way too long to Train
